# Is dimensionality reduction reversible?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, encog, som, dimensionality-reduction

I have implemented a dimentionality reduction algorithm using ENCOG, that takes a dataset (call it A) with multiple features and reduces it to a dataset (B) with only one feature (I need that for time series analisys).

Now my question is, I have a value from B - predicted by the time series analysis, can I convert it back to two dimensions like in the A dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimensionality reduction (compression of information) is reversible in auto-encoders. Auto-encoder is regular neural network with bottleneck layer in the middle. You have for instance 20 inputs in the first layer, 10 neurons in the middle layer and again 20 neurons in the last layer. When you train such network you force it to compress information to 10 neurons and then uncompress again minimizing error in the last layer(desired output vector equals input vector). When you use well known Back-propagation algorithm to train such network it performs PCA - Principal Component Analysis. PCA returns uncorrelated features. It's not very powerful.

By using more sophisticated algorithm to train auto-encoder you can make it perform nonlinear ICA - Independent Component Analysis. ICA returns statistically independent features. This training algorithm searches for low complexity neural networks with high generalization capability. As a byproduct of regularization you get ICA.

Comment: Thanks, I already figured myself that auto-encoders can do the reverse operation, of course accuracy sometimes not so good, but at least it is something.

Comment: @Mac, Could you provide a reference for your first sentence? I don't think this is true.

Comment: First half of network encodes, second half decodes. It can be immediately seen when you take look at architecture. What kind of reference do you need? What was the downvote for?

Comment: Below is a paper where you can find all info. It has many examples, one of them shows how PCA and even regular ICA fail, and non-linear ICA does not ftp://ftp.idsia.ch/pub/juergen/lococode.pdf

Comment: @Mac, minimizing error in training examples won't produce a reversible encoding. A reversible encoding can't have any error at all for any input.

Comment: It is reversible for all practical purposes. When you view jpeg image it is not perfect decompression either. So according to you jpeg compression is not reversible. You are not serious. You compress information - you learn. You create model of the data which is shorter than the data itself. Study Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: @Mac Jpeg is of course the most obvious example of non-reversible image compression.

Answer (score 2):

No, dimensionality reduction is not reversible in general. It loses information.